# Android application works fine in emulator but not in real device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, forceclose

I'm making a simple Music Player application. It already works perfectly on my emulator but after I install it on my device, it gives
*"The application `MusicShare` (process com.example.musicshare) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"*.

My device is a Galaxy S2 and I got the apk by taking it from the bin folder. I have tried using "Export w/o unsigned key and it cannot be installed instead. Here's the **manifest**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.musicshare"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayListActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's the error log from logcat after I debugged it on the device:

```
11-05 17:31:17.705: D/dalvikvm(6222): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 44K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 23ms
11-05 17:31:17.760: D/dalvikvm(6222): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 53% free 2575K/5379K, external 466K/518K, paused 28ms
11-05 17:31:17.790: D/AndroidRuntime(6222): Shutting down VM
11-05 17:31:17.790: W/dalvikvm(6222): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicshare/com.example.musicshare.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.example.musicshare.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.playSong(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:273)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.example.musicshare.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.onCreate(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:80)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-05 17:31:17.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Plug it in via USB and get the LogCat logs of the crash. That'll lead you (or us) in the right direction.

Comment: Can you try plugging your phone via USB and running your application with your phone (set your device as the the target). Then upon launching your application (and crashing), there will be logs in in your logcat area. Please post those messages (normally in red, indicating the errors), so we can have it analyzed.

Comment: Check your data, maybe he cant find directory or media files that exists on emulator, but doesn't exist on the phone

Comment: Your array in the playSong probably empty. What does that array list hold?

Comment: Should be the songs. I've set the path to "/sdcard/" (because in emulator, it should be "/mnt/sdcard/") but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pleerock is correct. Apparently it was the problem with the path. It should be "/sdcard/media/audio/Music/". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to export the whole project and get the .apk file and install it