# Load image from url. emulator work well but device not work

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I had develop a mobile apps to load image from URL path.

Here is my code.

```
    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;

        }catch (Exception e)
        {   
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
        }
    }
```

This method is work well in emulator which android API 10 but cannot work in android device. The device i use test is API 16 and 17.

Kindly look for help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you provided the internet permission ? Also make sure when you run in device you make internet connection ON.

Comment: Yea. Device had internet but not worked.

Comment: First Just print your imageUrl in log while running in Device....

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this?:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and yes, you must be connected to the internet.

Comment: I had use the INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifext. It not worked.

Comment: Is the path correct? go here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225456/android-application-works-fine-in-emulator-but-not-in-real-device

Answer (score 0):

**LotusUNSW** is right, you have to add INTERNET permission but if it's working on emulator it seems that this permission is set .

**EDIT :**
Alternatively, you can try using this method :

(last code was a stupid copy paste without checking, available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android))

**Don't forget to do this in a separate thread (using AsyncTask for example)**

But try this thing instead

```
private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
       }
       return bm;
    }
```

and then

```
Bitmap b = getImageBitmap("http://sdsdsdsdsdsdsds");
if (b != null)
  myImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Source :[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/jupslaeAEuo)

Comment: Is it full function ? copy and closeStream is undefined in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this code to a thread or AsyncTask. Http requests can't be done from main thread because of strict mode.Here check [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).